# Angular 4 app in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, angular

We want to develop an Angular 4 app outside of Wordpress and now package it somehow and plug it into 1..n Wordpress pages. Is making a Wordpress plugin what we would need for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have released a plugin, Xo for Angular, which aims to provide a foundation for WordPress and Angular. Xo provides a capability to host and load your Angular App as a theme within WordPress that integrates nicely with pages, posts, etc.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/xo-for-angular/

It is currently in beta and would appreciate any feedback!

Main concepts:

- Your Angular project exists as a theme within WordPress.
- Angular templates (modules) which can be selected for pages and posts.
- Dynamic routing of pages, posts, and other content created in WordPress.

Documentation (work in progress): https://angularxo.io/

Plugin github: https://github.com/WarriorRocker/angular-xo-core

Example theme: https://github.com/WarriorRocker/angular-xo-material

Let me know what you think, thanks!

Comment: A little late for my usecase, but this looks very promising.